# Strange org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException

Tags: java, mysql, sql, spring, jdbc

So, I am using Spring in my project, with JDBC to manage the Database part.

When a person tries to register, after filling the form, this method is called:

```
@Override
public String addUser(Usuario user) {
public static String SQLADDUSER="insert into users(NOMBRE, PASSWORD, EMAIL, NEWSLETTER) values=(?,?,?,?)";
    getJdbcTemplate().update(SQLADDUSER,new Object[]{user.getNombre(), user.getPass(), user.getEmail(),user.isNewsletter()});
    return "ok";
}
```

I have some sysouts there to see that user.getNombre(), etc. are not null. They HAVE the proper values.

I have some other schemas in the database (I am using MySQL), and one of them is marked as default schema. But, in other part of this app, I do a select * from users, and users return well.

I am declaring my datasource bean this way:

```
<beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"></beans:property>
    <beans:property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/theproperschema"></beans:property>
    <beans:property name="username" value="root"></beans:property>
    <beans:property name="password" value="root"></beans:property>
</beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></beans:property>
</beans:bean>
```

The table users has 4 columns, aside of id column (Primary key): nombre, pass, email(those three are varchar) and newsletter (is a Binary).

And, when I try to insert this, I have this exception:

```
Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [insert into users(NOMBRE, PASSWORD, EMAIL, NEWSLETTER) values=(?,?,?,?)]; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '=('jarl','nopuedor','tedacuen',1)' at line 1] con causa raíz
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '=('jarl','nopuedor','tedacuen',1)' at line 1
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:381)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1030)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3491)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3423)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1936)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2060)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2542)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1734)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2019)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1937)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1922)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$2.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:818)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$2.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:1)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:587)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:812)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:868)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:876)
at my.package.Dao.UserDaoImp.addUser(UserDaoImp.java:59)
at my.package.Services.UsuarioServiceImp.addUser(UsuarioServiceImp.java:44)
at my.package.Controllers.NewUserFormController.addUsuario(NewUserFormController.java:37)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:213)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

I dont know where the error is. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the equal sign `=` in your SQL query

```
insert into users(NOMBRE, PASSWORD, EMAIL, NEWSLETTER) values=(?,?,?,?)
```

Just write this instead

```
insert into users(NOMBRE, PASSWORD, EMAIL, NEWSLETTER) values(?,?,?,?)
```

Comment: ...Im ashamed. Of course, it worked. Thank you, I will upvote when I can do it...

Comment: It happens. There is nothing to be ashamed of ;)